# Issue when selecting desired elements from dict_keys in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, extract

I have a list of dictionary keys `['A_report1', 'A_report2', ..., 'A_report10','B_report1', 'B_report2', ..., 'B_report10',]`. I want to extract all 'report1' from this dict_keys. In other words, I should only get `'A_report1'` and `'B_report1'`.

Here's the code I tried:

```
[report for report in list(dictionary.keys()) if 'report1' in report]
```

Issue: It'll return `'A_report10'` and `'B_report10'` as well, I only want report1's. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Did that code not work?

Comment: It will also return report10, since the string report10 includes report1

Comment: Note, `for report in list(df.keys())` could just be `for report in df`, there is no need to call `.keys()` and there is *certainly* no need to turn that into a `list(...)`

Comment: Anyway, maybe `[report for report in df if report.endswith("report1")]`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I changed the confusing name "df" to "dictionary". The actual problem I have is a dictionary and I only want to get the right elements among the keys. In this case, should I use dictionary.keys() or still just use dictionary is enough?@juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @Jiamei yes. iterating over a dictionary directly iterates over its keys. And again, you **never** need to add `list` if youa re doing something like `[x for x in list(whatever) if something]` you can *always* just do `[x for x in whatever if something]` (assuming you aren't doing any side-effects which mutate `whatever`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a regular expression?

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'report1\b')
items = [report for report in df if rx.search(report)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it returned an empty list. I assume it's because the regular expression you have here? Anything I need to add before 'report1\b'? The name I have are A_report1, B_report1, ..

Comment: Oops, use `rx.search` instead of `rx.match`.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple but non-robust solution based on the assumption that all your report names follow the format `.*report<any int number>`:

```
x = ['A_report10', 'B_report1', 'B_report2', 'B_report10']

report_1s = []

for i in x:
    if i[-7:]=='report1':
        report_1s.append(i)
        print(i)
```

Comment: Please include at least a broad description of your approach, so how you solve the question is more obvious (rather than requires code analysis)

Comment: Would work except if the list included 'A_report11' or 'B_report111'